# JAVA ME Socket send and receive

Tags: sockets, java-me

I wanted to make an app that when the user press by example (m) on the keyboard the mobile device connects to the server which is made with C# ,and i want it to send a Word and wait for a response , can anybody help me with that because that is my first JAVA ME Application
(i've made a C# Code Client For Testing , if anybody wants to see it so that he can convert it to JAVA ME just comment)

Answer (score 1):

To handle a single key stroke you will need low level graphics with Canvas. Please go through this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-j2me2/

`keyPressed` method will trigger a new connection to your server. See this other tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wi-jio/

Comment: thanks , but the problem with me isn't in the code, its hard to make an interface in Java ME , do you have a tutorial on how to make a good interface (buttons,labels and textboxes)

Comment: If you can use LWUIT go through this tutorial http://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/index.html